# i want to know how i program fix-height-div and flexible-height-div

Tags: css

I have a programming website in CSS. During programming, I found one problem.
if display-size is changed, under div is rising. so, I want to solve this problem to add sub-div when display-size is changed. in the picture which i attach, i only want to show div 1, and when user scroll, show other under div. and when display-size is changed, i add sub-div(=div2 in the picture). (div 1 background color and div 2 background color is same. so it seems that it is only div 1. because of the same color) how should I program this?

[image: attached picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand you question proper, but as per scenario given in attachment following things you need to do

```
.div1 {
height: 200px //fixed height for div1
}

.div2 {
display: none;
height: auto;
}
```

and using jquery you can target on scroll event to show div2

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
if($(window).pageYOffset > 0) {
$('.div2).show();
}
else {
$('.div2).hide();
})
```

and for mobile write media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
//write your css code for div1 and div2 here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting clearly what you want to achieve, but if your goal is to combine a fixed-size element, and give the rest of the space to an other, flexible element, flexbox could help:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixedSizeDiv"></div>
    <div class="flexibleDiv"></div>
</div>
```

with styles like:

```
.parent {
   /* maybe height property need to be set, depending on your wrapper element layout properties... */
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
}

.fixedSizeDiv {
    flex-basis: 200px; /*or whatever*/
}

.flexibleDiv { flex:1; }
```